# Create map of User and corresponding List of Accounts

Tags: apex, class, map, loop, set

I have an object where exist an Account and user lookup fields. Now records of the object will have always user and Account combination as unique. It means U1 -A1 combination can not exist in multiple records of the object. I have to create a map of User Id and List of it's corresponding Account Ids. I tried below but it somehow not even prints in debug log. So I am unable to understand where is my mistake. Can someone please help here?

**Apex Code**

```
Map<Id,Set<Id>> MapOfTierObj = new Map<Id,Set<Id>>();
// Change in map assign 
for(Tier_abv__c Tr: scope)
{
   if(!MapOfTierObj.containsKey(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c))
   {
       MapOfTierObj.put(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c, new Set<ID>{Tr.Account_abv__c});
   }else{
         MapOfTierObj.get(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c).add(Tr.Account_abv__c);
          system.debug('Add Accounts to existing@'+MapOfTierObj.get(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c)); }    
   }

    system.debug('MapOfTierObj@'+MapOfTierObj);
    // Change in Map assign : Completed
```

Here the scope comes from here:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Query =  'SELECT id,Account_abv__c,Account_abv__r.Commercial_Core_Panel_Target_abv__c,Core_Panel_User_abv__c '+
            'from Tier_abv__c Where Core_Panel_User_abv__c != NULL AND Account_abv__r.Commercial_Core_Panel_Target_abv__c = True '+
             'order by Core_Panel_User_abv__c asc';

          Abbvie_Custom_Settings__c AbvSetngs = Abbvie_Custom_Settings__c.getInstance('Main');
                  if(AbvSetngs !=null)
                  {
                   ListName = AbvSetngs.Commercial_Core_Panel_Target_List_Name__c;   
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                      ListName = 'My Core Panel with Recent Comm Visit';
                  }

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please also post the start method?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get the start method. Which one please tell me?

Comment: Hi. If you add a basic system.debug in the  beginning of the for loop, does it print something in the log? If not, the variable scope must be empty.

Comment: Where is the `Scope` coming from if its a list then add a debug and check whether it holds any value before iteration of for loop

Comment: Did you try to verify that your scope variable is not empty?

Comment: Check the batch job by monitoring apex job and check whether there are actually any records processed or you can use a debug before the for loop to check as per the above comments.I think there are no records to process here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing putting set value to map. I will recommend writing it in below form:

```
for(Tier_abv__c Tr: scope)
{
   Set<Id> idSet=new Set<Id> ();
   if(MapOfTierObj.containsKey(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c))
      idSet=MapOfTierObj.get(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c);
   idSet.add(Tr.Account_abv__c)
   MapOfTierObj.put(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c,idSet);

}
```

Here is adiitional information to explain what was wrong with your code:

```
else{
         MapOfTierObj.get(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c).add(Tr.Account_abv__c);
          system.debug('Add Accounts to existing@'+MapOfTierObj.get(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c)); }    
   }
```

Above code snippet will definitely add a value to set but will not update your map with revised set. So you could have written this as:

```
MapOfTierObj.put(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c,MapOfTierObj.get(Tr.Core_Panel_User_abv__c).add(Tr.Account_abv__c));
```

Comment: He doesn't need it. He's updating the set by adding one id in it.

Comment: @Mukesh. Thanks I am getting exact values in my debug now. But still I didn't get where I was wrong. But Thanks i was able to work with this. :)

Comment: @SFDC_Learner : Improved answer to explain what was wrong.